# Which directory is the real location that `brew cask install` uses?

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Which directory is the real location that `brew cask install` uses?

I want to find the real location of app, not the symlink in `/Application`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can find custom commands for each application amongst available [Casks](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/tree/master/Casks), but generally, `brew cask install` just retrieves the configured version of the executable file and moves it to the specified application directory (~/Applications by default).

`/usr/local/Caskroom` contains the list of casks installed, and `.metadata` folder in each cask mentions the cask file used during installation.

The app directory you see in `~/Applications` is **not** a symlink. If it is so, check that app's cask file and it should contain clues to the real location.

Comment: `/usr/local/Caskroom` does not exist on M1

Comment: On Apple Silicon, the path is `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom`.

Answer (score 10):

Furthermore, apart from what @Subhash Bhushan explained, if you want to know where exactly a formula has been installed you can use the command `info`

```
brew info --cask <formula>
```

For example for atom:

```
brew info --cask atom

atom: 1.32.2 (auto_updates)
https://atom.io/
/usr/local/Caskroom/atom/1.32.2 (64B)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/atom.rb
==> Name
Github Atom
==> Artifacts
Atom.app (App)
/Users/username/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/apm (Binary)
/Users/username/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh -> atom (Binary)
```

In this example, the artifact is installed in `~/Appplications`.

Comment: It should be `brew info --cask formula`