# Is it possible to change the default app directory for home-brew casks to an external hard drive?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am running out of space on my laptop, and I was wondering if it would be possible to change the default directory of installing casks on an external hard drive so that I can use the internal hard drive just for the OS and important files.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can overwrite the environment variable `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS` or you can use the `--appdir=/my/path` option. You can get more information with the command `man brew-cask` and there is a nice markdown [documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/USAGE.md#options) in the cask repository. [Otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254149/which-directory-is-the-real-location-that-brew-cask-install-use#:%7E:text=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2FCaskroom%20contains,Applications%20is%20not%20a%20symlink.) the executables can be found in the `Applications` folder.

**EDIT**:

Sometimes it helps to run a cleanup to delete the old versions:

```sh
brew cleanup
brew cask cleanup
```

Comment: How would I be able to overwrite `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS`?

Comment: You can set the varibale in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshenv` file.

Comment: I used `nano ~/.bash_profile` to add the line that it says in the documentation, but now it creates a new folder when I reinstall instead of putting the casks in the external hard drive.

Comment: Which path did you use? Where is the new folder? Have you looked at the other possibilities with man brew-cask? With the option `HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS` you only change the folder of the executable file.

Comment: Nvm I had to change my external hard drive name to make it easier for the program to minimize reading errors